# Как сделать чтоб выпадающий дропдаун не обрезался в блоке с overlfow: auto и максимальной высотой?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок с максимальной высотой и overflow: auto внутри и в нем список с итемами в которых есть кнопка которая при клике открывает дропдаун с фиксированной высотой, у дропдауна position: absolute; right: 0; top: 100%; .
Проблема в том что блок который обрезается обрезает также дропдаун когда блок проскроллен в самый вниз. Как правильно написать условие на JS чтоб дропдаун понимал когда нужно менять top значение в тот момент когда он может обрезаться хотя бы частично из-за обрезаного блока родителя?

Comment: Добрый день, можете дополнить ваш вопрос с кодом?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого сам выпадающий список должен находится в `body` и иметь `position: fixed` и большой `z-index`. Чтобы выпадающий список был под селектом, вычисляешь координаты селекта через `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` и у выпадающего списка меняешь свойства `top, left, width`. Еще все эти вычисления нужно обновлять при скролле страницы, либо отключить скролл страницы при открытии селекта

Comment: Не обязательно в body, если у родителя с overflow установлен position: static, то абсолютно спозиционированный dropdown будет спозиционирован по родителю с position:absolute/relative и проигнорирует overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Вывести блок из под *overflow: hidden* можно с помощью родителя. Остаётся только спозиционировать dropdown относительно нужного элемента с помощью js.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.wrap {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.overflow {
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='overflow'>
    <div class='dropdown'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```